# create columns dynamically using range of values

Tags: sas

I wasn't able to find a previous post that answered my query - will be happy to follow link to duplicate post.

I want to dynamically create columns based on range (in SAS) - something like below, which doesn't work

```
data work.test;
    set sashelp.air;
    format mb monyy.;
    do i = 1 to 10;
        mb&i = intnx('MONTH', date, -i, 'same');
    end;
run;
```

The expected result is 10 new columns called `mb1` to `mb10` with the respective `date-interval` value.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting macro involved that you don't need.  Notice I create array MB and replace the MB&I with an array reference.  I don't have SASHELP.AIR so just used today() but you get the idea.

```
data work.test;
   *set sashelp.air;;
   array mb[10];
   date = today();
   do i = 1 to dim(mb);
      mb[i] = intnx('MONTH', date, -i, 'same');
      end;
   format mb: monyy.;
   run;
```